# Is there a name for this emotion or emotion-related effect?

Tags: emotion, terminology

This is about a positive emotion or "wibe" (I call it here "an emotion-related effect") that a person may feel in their chest/heart in certain cases.

This feeling can appear at any time. I think most commonly it would appear from a positive *expectation* but not the kind that is based on the person consciously thinking of a positive outcome. Rather cases that a gambler perhaps would describe as "I don't know why but I just feel strongly that I will win this time".

(Maybe it is related to wishing a specific outcome.)

I am not sure if this description is too shallow to qualify as a question here.

Is there a professional term that is used for this emotion-related effect?

Comment: This is probably what is called "elevation emotion" but am not sure if that is a formal term.